# Batch change attributes in template properties in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, features, batch, template

I am using a number of feature templates for mapping and would like to change a specific attribute in all templates with the same value without going through the list and change every single feature template.

Is there an option at a higher level to avoid this time-killing job?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you can do this in ArcMap so I think it should be possible in ArcGIS Pro as well. You can modify attribute values for multiple selected features in a layer at the same time by selecting multiple templates in the Map Templates pane before clicking the Edit Properties button.
Please refer this for more details:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/applying-the-same-attribute-values-to-multiple-features-in-a-layer.htm